# Control Layout Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, listview, ascx

I need a way to layout controls in a page.
Let me ask you by example.
I have four different action buttons (Edit, Delete, etc..) that do the same actions on any page, but sometimes I want them laid out horizontally and some other times vertically, depending on which page is displaying them.
So I thought of placing all four buttons in a user control and manage their layout using some sort of template control.

Does such a control exist that is as flexible as ListView's template management?
Of course a lazy solution is to place four buttons horizontally in a panel, and another four buttons vertically in another panel, and show/hide the panel that's requested, but I don't want to have two instances of the buttons; I just want one instance of each button, but in different layouts.

Feel free to add more tags to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such thing can be achieved with CSS. I'm bad in CSS but I believe this works:

HTML

```
<div class="horizontal">
    <input type="button" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="2" />
    <input type="button" value="3" />
    <input type="button" value="4" />
</div>
```

Two CSS classes you simply set which you need in the div element (you can wrap your buttons with UserControl and map div's class to UserControl's property)

```
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .horizontal input 
        {
            margin:0px 2px 0px 2px;
        }

        .vertical input
        {
            display:block;
            margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
```

Templated control is to strong for such easy task especially when you do not need to change template content.

Comment: That's awfully embarrassing.  Thanks =)